# MySQL where or composite index : will it be faster when performing two separate search?

Tags: mysql, select, indexing, query-optimization

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `FooBar` (
  `id` int,
  `foo` int,
  `bar1` int,
  `bar2` int,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `foobar1` (`foo`, `bar1`),
  KEY `foobar2` (`foo`, `bar2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now I have the following select query:

```
select * from FooBar where foo=1 and (bar1=2 or bar2=2);
```

And the alternative two consecutive selects

```
select * from FooBar where foo=1 and bar1=2;
select * from FooBar where foo=1 and bar2=2;
```

Will the time of the single select with "or" be significantly faster, slower or around the same comparing with the total time of the two consecutive selects?

Comment: Can I suggest that you test it and find out

Comment: I don't have a test environment currently set up for testing large amount of data in order to notice a difference, and MySQL behavior is pretty random for small data sets.

Comment: Yes, testing this is the way to go. Keep in mind that doing two queries could result in a lot of duplicates which you then might have to remove. This depends heavily on the data, so preferably use some real data instead of 'foo' and 'bar'.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have sufficient data to get a proper testing environment. In a small dataset with like 20 rows the "explain" I got show none of the keys are used for the "or" case and I am pretty sure it wouldn't be the case when there is enough data.

Comment: "Explain" can only tell you so much, in the end it is the execution time and resources usage, which you can achieve in practice, that are relevant. It is good that you see these two options, so later, when you do have real data, you can try it out. Basically we cannot answer a hypothetical question like this. The answer probably depends on many, many factors.

Comment: Use one of the many free online tools to build yourself a more useful test dataset. Doing your development and testing with only a handful of rows means you do not discover the issues until production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.

- OR kills performance -- usually leading to ignoring the index and scanning the whole table.
- Two separate queries -- there is lots of overhead in handling a statement; it is usually much better to combine two statements (unless that leads to other inefficiencies).

The usual speedup for `OR` is `UNION`:

```
( select * from FooBar where foo=1 and bar1=2 )
UNION ALL
( select * from FooBar where foo=1 and bar2=2 )
;
```

`UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION DISTINCT`, but `ALL` could lead to duplicate rows.  Pick accordingly.

(If there will be `ORDER BY` or pagination, the discussion gets longer.)

If `bar1` and `bar2` is an example of an "array" spread across columns, this becomes an argument for *not* designing the schema that way.  Instead, this  might be better as a table with one "bar" column, and have (potentially) multiple rows for each `foo`.

A simple example of that is a table of persons where you want to include their phone number(s).  It is much better to have a table with (person_id, phone_num) -- and the numbers could be for cell, landline, fax, work, home, etc, etc.  It is open-ended, zero or more, etc.

Timing...  True, having just a few rows makes it difficult to predict performance as the data grows.  Here's one trick; it counts the rows involved, hence can easily discover that `OR` touches every row in the table:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts -- 20 rows should be fine.  If a Handler count says 19 or 20, then it did a table scan.  About 40 would indicate 2 scans.  I predict

- 20 for your `OR` query;
- 2 for your two separate Selects (but this does not take into account the overhead of every query)
- 2 for my `UNION ALL`
- 4 or 6 for my `UNION DISTINCT`, plus 2 writes (for a necessary temp table).

The 20 clearly won't scale well to millions of rows; all the rest will.

`EXPLAIN` has a lot of issues with counts.  Still, *in this case*, it might be nearly as good as my Handler technique.

There are no tools that can tell you "what you should have done".  (Stackoverflow comes close, but it is very labor intensive.)